# How to query the schema info in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, database-schema

I am getting the following error:

> `ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

I understand this is because I am trying to use a leader node function only but is there some other way to do the same thing?

I am running this in the Amazon Data Pipeline on Redshift Database.

```
CREATE TABLE "schema_n"."temp_variable"
AS    
SELECT CASE WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM PG_TABLE_DEF pgtd WHERE schemaname = 'schema_xyz' AND tablename = 'table_xyz')) OR (DATE_PART('dow', CURRENT_DATE) = 0)
         THEN '2017-01-01'::DATE 
        ELSE CURRENT_DATE - 11
        END AS "date_import";
```

I've also tried:

```
CREATE TABLE "schema_n"."temp_variable"
AS    
SELECT CASE WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'schema_xyz' AND table_name = 'table_xyz')) OR (DATE_PART('dow', CURRENT_DATE) = 0)
          THEN '2017-01-01'::DATE 
        ELSE CURRENT_DATE - 11
        END AS "date_import";
```

Basically I am trying to do the following:

If table_xyz does not exist or if it's Sunday, return '2017-01-01' otherwise return today-11 days.

Whatever I try, I keep getting the same error:

> `ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

Comment: Sorry, I have added SELECT at the beginning of the CASE statement. Basically, I am storing this return in a table and later use it as a time variable for the ETL.

Comment: @JonScott They work when run from a client, but in the pipeline they return a message.

Comment: I didn't know that ctas won't work here. I changed it to proper table declaration and it's still returning the same mistake.

Comment: the only workaround is to run the select query OUTSIDE of redshift (e.g. a python script) returning the values to the python script and then in the next step (inside the script) insert those values in to your target table. This info doesn't help you if you are using data pipeline. Consider moving to Apache Airflow for greater control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the only thing that worked in the pipeline is to do this using svv_table_info table.

```
CREATE TABLE "schema_n"."temp_variable" (
   "date_import" DATE;

INSERT INTO "schema_n"."temp_variable"
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM svv_table_info WHERE "schema" = 'schema_xyz' AND "table" = 'table_xyz')) OR (DATE_PART('dow', CURRENT_DATE) = 0)
        THEN '2017-01-01'::DATE 
    ELSE CURRENT_DATE - 11
    END AS "date_import";
```